# How flip page after time interval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I use template `Page-Based Application`(`RootViewController`, `DataViewController`, `ModelController`) in Xcode. I want to flip page after time interval. How can I do it?

Code for flip next page

```
    - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help you

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:nav.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                    //Action to Implement
                            }];
```

[or]

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[[self navigationController] presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{
               //Action to implement
            }];
```

Comment: you can use this code on which controller you want to flip.

Comment: ex:controller A is your current class then add this code for certain action then code will flip to another controller B

Comment: Here A is your current class and B is your Destination.In my code HomeviewController is my Destination.

Comment: Update my question. How can use your and my code together?

Comment: for this case there one option in storyboard called Transition Style use that.

Comment: select the parent controller and set the transition style to Flip Horizontal

Comment: use the First segment code in that From view and toview is same for your case (ie) the controller that you want to flip

Answer (score 0):

To flip after time interval use dispatch_after.

```
// define fromViewController depend on your previous code
UIViewController *toViewController = [self pageViewController:pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:viewController];
// or set another toViewController depend on your previous  code

NSTimeInterval interval = 5; //in seconds
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView transitionFromView:fromViewController.view toViewController:toViewController.view duration:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //completion block
    }];
});
```

Comment: Please look at the screen

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0EJbcHq3ZALRVQxbGhfcHVpeDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I worte "Define fromViewController in you code". I little change my answer.

Comment: you have to adjust this snippet to your code. I don't know names of your controllers in code.